# Trouble when using remote validation with MVC5's route attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

Since I switched to using MVC5's route attributes, I'm getting a 'no url for remote validation could be found' exception.

Here's my public property

```
[Remote("IsEmailAddressValid", "SignUp")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

and here's my validation method/route:

```
[Route("is-email-address-valid/{emailAddress}")]
public JsonResult IsEmailAddressValid(string emailAddress)
{
    ...
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why you are using `Route` are you validating your email outside your application using APIs

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute routing with remote validation. Here is how.

Your public property:

```
[Remote("IsEmailAddressValid")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Your validation method/route:

```
[Route("is-email-address-valid", Name = "IsEmailAddressValid")]
public JsonResult IsEmailAddressValid(string emailAddress)
{
    ...
}
```

This way ASP.NET will get the route from the route name supplied in the route attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the RouteAttribute from your validation action.